# How to visualize ReactJS+redux dataflow, store and component hierarchy

Tags: reactjs, mysql-workbench, visualization, redux, diagram

In order to set up correctly our team's project and share knowledge efficiently, I'd like to visually represent our reactjs + redux structure.

For a mySQL database, I would use mySQL Workbench.

What would be the best option for a reactJS + redux application ?

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT**

Following the first responses, I'd lie to add that I'm looking for a visual way to represent a component and store hierarchy to help build the UI. I'd like to use diagrams, etc. Skipper for ORM is something similar to what I'm looking for.
Microsoft Visio could be too. but I'm wondering if there is not something more relevant to redux + reactjs.

Answer (score 2):

For ReactJS I suggest you install React DevTools for chrome. It will allow you to visualize your UI structure. See here:
 https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

For **Redux** there are also devtools which are super useful to get all the actions and state changes in your app:

> Redux DevTools is a development time package that provides power-ups
>   for your Redux development workflow.

- [Redux devtools github](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools)
- [Redux devtools chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en)

For **React**

> React Developer Tools is a system that allows you to inspect a React
>   Renderer, including the Component hierarchy, props, state, and more.

- [React devtools github](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools)
- [React devtools chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)